# Como bloquear o acesso à um hostname

Tags: linux, firewall

Eu preciso bloquear o acesso ao site `www.facebook.com` de uma máquina Linux. Eu devo bloquear isso na própria máquina, isto é, eu não tenho a possibilidade de fazer isso com um Proxy.

Inicialmente eu pensei em usar o iptables, porém, como o Facebook possui IP dinâmico, e o iptables resolve o hostname somente no momento da adição da regra, o site pode ser acessado em alguns momentos (quando o IP de acesso mudar).
Existe um jeito simples para fazer isso?

Comment: Inclua o seguinte no arquivo `/etc/hosts`: `facebook.com 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisa forçar todas as requisições DNS (porta 53 UDP e TCP) a passarem pelo seu próprio *resolver* (por exemplo, um servidor de DNS que faça consultas recursivas), pois nada impede do usuário configurar um DNS diferente na própria máquina. Direcionando todas as requisições para o seu servidor, você terá uma facilidade maior de fazer o bloqueio. Para isto, o `iptables` resolve bem (redirecionando tudo que for porta 53, independente de nome ou IP).

Ex: o usuário coloca o servidor 208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS) como DNS na máquina-cliente, porém suas rotas redirecionam qualquer acesso à porta 53 para o seu próprio servidor, não permitindo que a requisição saia da rede interna. Assim que qualquer usuário digitar www.facebook.com, o seu servidor é que vai ser consultado (lembrando que tem o m.facebook.com, e mais uma série de coisas que pode ser filtrada).

Após isso,precisa configurar o seu próprio servidor DNS, como no exemplo dado pelo bfavaretto, ou customizando a configuração do DNS instalado no servidor de acordo com a documentação.

> Mesmo assim, alguém poderia rodar um servidor local de DNS, que fizesse uma requisição externa em outra porta que não a 53, escapando do bloqueio (raro acontecer, mas é bom que você saiba do risco). Ou simplesmente por os IPs desejados no arquivo `hosts` da própria máquina.

Se for pra uso em empresas, muitas vezes a solução é colocar no contrato do trabalho dos funcionários a proibição, e uma cláusula dando ciência de que há monitoração remota das telas, e o primeiro que "escorregar", uma advertência por escrito. Assim você vai evitar um monte de problemas "infiltráveis" de maneira mais eficaz, incluindo uso pessoal indevido das máquinas, e evitando uma alegação de invasão de privacidade por parte do funcionário (desde que ele tenha ciência plena da monitoração).